# How to add or implement image in Decision Tree

Tags: java

I was wondering if you could add an image to a decision so that way when the user gets to the final question it displays an image that matches what the user has inputted

```
    <import java.util.Scanner;    
/**
 * Decision Tree implemented for people choosing a car brand based on specific qualifications
 * or characteristics.
 * @author Bart
 *
 */
public class CarBrandExpert {
     private LinkedBinaryTree<String> tree;

       //-----------------------------------------------------------------
       //  Sets up the diagnosis question tree.
       //-----------------------------------------------------------------
       public CarBrandExpert()
       {
          String e1 = "Do you like american cars?";
          String e2 = "Do you like fast cars? ";
          String e3 = "Do you like sports cars?";
          String e4 = "Do you like car durability? ";
          String e5 = "Do you like sleek designs?";
          String e6 = "Do you like off road driving?";
          String e7 = "You like heavy duty?";
          String e8 = "Do you like easy car handles while driving?";
          String e9 = "Does size matter??";
          String e10 = "Do nice interiors catch your eye?";
          String e11 = "Love to drive in style?";
          String e12 = "Does gas milage matter? ";
          String e13 = "Do you have an expensive taste?";
          String e14 = "Toyota is your brand! ";
          String e15 = " Nissan is your Brand! ";
          String e16 = "An Audi is what you need!";
          String e17 = "BMW suits you best!";
          String e18 = "Fords are for your basic needs based upon your data";
          String e19 = "Chevy is the BOMB! Definitely worth a try!";
          String e20 = "Try Chrysler";
          String e21 = "Dodges should quinch your thrist and relieve your worries";
//Creates the nodes in order to match the outcomes with the right questions as well predict the different outcome of users answer

          LinkedBinaryTree<String> n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9,
             n10, n11, n12, n13, n14, n15, n16, n17, n18, n19, n20, n21;



          n14 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String>(e14);
          n15 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String>(e15);
          n12 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String>(e12, n14, n15);


          n16 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String>(e16);
          n17 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String>(e17);
          n13 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String>(e13, n16, n17);

          n18 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String>(e18);
          n19 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String>(e19);
          n11 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String>(e11, n18, n19);

          n20 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String>(e20);
          n21 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String>(e21);
          n7 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String>(e7, n20, n21);

          n2 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String>(e2, n12, n13);
          n3 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String>(e3, n11, n7);


          tree = new LinkedBinaryTree<String>(e1, n2, n3);


       }
         /*
          * Prints out the decision based on the answer of yes or no
          * Also helps to check which side of the tree the program should go on in order to find predicted answer
          */

       public void Matchup()
          {
             Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
             BinaryTree<String> current = tree;

             System.out.println ("So,you're looking to find the right car brand?");
             while (current.size() > 1)
             {
                System.out.println (current.getRootElement());
                if (scan.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
                   current = current.getLeft();
                else 
                   current = current.getRight();
             }

             System.out.println (current.getRootElement());
          }    






}>

    <public class CarBrandMatchUp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CarBrandExpert car = new CarBrandExpert();

        car.Matchup();

    }

}>
```

I was thinking for each outcome the user would be matched up with a specific car brand and it would display a random car of that brand any ideas of how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your wondering how to display an image, I got this code java's documentation (Can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/examples/LoadImageApp.java)):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * This class demonstrates how to load an Image from an external file
 */
public class LoadImageApp extends Component {

    BufferedImage img;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public LoadImageApp() {
       try {
           img = ImageIO.read(new File("strawberry.jpg"));
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }

    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (img == null) {
             return new Dimension(100,100);
        } else {
           return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Load Image Sample");

        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

        f.add(new LoadImageApp());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

You could create a string variable with the image name and change it depending on which node the user ends on in the tree. Hope this helps you get in the right direction at least.

Comment: Okay i tried that way and it didint work but i found another way to display an image but how to i implement the method or class into the decision Tree \